# Dúvida cache asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, cache

Tenho o seguinte cenário:

```
Public ActionResult ProdutoFornecedor01()
{
     var produtos = _db.Produtos.Include(x => x.Fornecedor).OrderByDescending(x => x.ProdutoId).Where(x => x.Fornecedor.Id == 1).Take(10);
     return PartialView("_PartialProdutosFornecedor01", produtos);
}

Public ActionResult ProdutoFornecedor02()
{
     var produtos = _db.Produtos.Include(x => x.Fornecedor).OrderByDescending(x => x.ProdutoId).Where(x => x.Fornecedor.Id == 2).Take(10);
     return PartialView("_PartialProdutosFornecedor02", produtos);
}

Public ActionResult ProdutoFornecedor03()
{
     var produtos = _db.Produtos.Include(x => x.Fornecedor).OrderByDescending(x => x.ProdutoId).Where(x => x.Fornecedor.Id == 3).Take(10);
     return PartialView("_PartialProdutosFornecedor03", produtos);
}
```

Na minha `View` Index eu chamo as `PartialView`:

```
<div class="row">
     @Url.Action("ProdutoFornecedor01", "Produtos")
</div>

<div class="row">
     @Url.Action("ProdutoFornecedor02", "Produtos")
</div>

<div class="row">
     @Url.Action("ProdutoFornecedor03", "Produtos")
</div>
```

Segundo o meu Plano de Hospedagem, está havendo muitas requisições no banco de dados.

Tentei usar um `Cache`:

`[OutputCache(Duration = 600, VaryByParam = "*")]`

Porém o cliente reclamou que ao atualizar com um novo produto ele demora para aparecer na Home.

Qual a melhor maneira de contornar esse problema?

Comment: Amigo, tirando o fato que você poderia ter um método para fornecedor genérico ao invés de criar um método pra cada id, Você poderia jogar tudo pra memória assim diminuindo a quantidade de acesso ao banco, Tente alocar esses dados na memória e só faz uma requisição no banco caso essa memória esteja vazia. Se caso ocorrer algum cadastro salve e atualize essa memória.

Answer (score 1):

@Hermes

Primeiro, vai depender da quantidade de registros que você está enviando. Você pode chamar de forma async com o Entity Framework

Uma das formas para se carregar mais "rápido" sua Home, é você carregar suas views de forma async com ajax.

Da seguinte forma:
Na sua view

```
<div class="row">
   <div class="partial" data-url=@Url.Action("Action","Controller")></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="partial" data-url=@Url.Action("Action","Controller")></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <div class="partial" data-url=@Url.Action("Action","Controller")></div>
</div>
```

e seu js:

```
$('.partial').each(function(index,item) { 
   var url = $(item).data("url");
   if(url && url.length >0) {
     $(item).load(url);
   }
});
```

Comment: A quantidade vai ser sempre a mesma. Sempre listará por exemplo os últimos 10 produtos cadastrados por categoria. Achei muito interessante seu exemplo, porém faria a requisição ao banco de dados do mesmo jeito, preciso de algo que diminua as requisições.

Comment: @HermesAutran Vendo pelo seu código, você busca todas as informações de Produtos e Fornecedores, já tentou usar select e buscar apenas o que precisa?

Comment: Editei a Pergunta. No caso, buscarei os 10 últimos registros de produtos de cada Fornecedor que eu desejo mostrar na Home. Como os produtos são incluídos por cada Fornecedor de forma aleatória, não seria legal dar um select e trazer todos os produtos e depois separa-los certo?

Answer (score 1):

Você pode manter o cache, e durante a inserção de um produto pelo cliente, fazer a atualização do cache referente à lista de produtos deste cliente, como se fosse um `TRIGGER`.

Dessa maneira o cache só é atualizado quando um produto é inserido, suponho eu que seja com menos frequência e diminuirá o acesso ao BD.